# Background service stops on Android Marshmallow 6.0+ devices

Tags: android, service

When app goes in background (by pressing home button). When screen goes off, after 15-20 mins the background service stops on Android M (6.0) phone. Although it works fine on phone with Lollipop (5.0).

Comment: It happens when a device runs out of memory, it gets "stopped" to free up memory.

Comment: Read about Background Limitations for Android M,N and So on .

Comment: Put your code in question and on which device you are testing your app?

Comment: Device I'm testing is HTC U Play (6.0) is having 4 GB RAM. Not having any other apps running on phone. So out of memory can't be the problem. One more thing, its happening on other 6.0+ devices as well.

Comment: you should return  `START_STICKY`  in onStartCommand(). It will restart your service even if it's stopped by os for any reasons like out of memory or any other.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I've already added START_STICKY but instead of that its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android M introduced Doze and App Standby which limits background services in order to preserve battery. How to handle Doze can be found in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) official android training manual.

edit:
Although not part of the original question, if you want to support Android O you will also have to keep the new  Background Execution Limits in mind. How to do this can be found in [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) official android training manual.

Comment: Above topic has helped me alot as well. I've added Manfiest permission REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS as well following above topic. Second change I did is of setting alarm by setAndAllowWhileIdle. Its working on every phone now. Thanks !!

Comment: Tested on phone with 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 and its working perfectly alright. But still not working on Android 8.0 !!

Comment: Your original question was about why it stopped working on Android 6, but I've updated my answer with information why it's not working on Android 8.

Comment: I'm unable to resolve this issue on Android 8.0. Someone please help me resolve it there.

Answer (score 1):

As you say in comment that you have started your service as **START_STICKY** and even it's not working in android marshmallow devices in background.

1. You should make sure that the device on which you are testing your app contains auto start permissions? If yes then you have to give auto start permission to your app otherwise your service can't run in background.
2. Even after following above step your problem is not solved then i suggest to use Alarmmanager in following way to start your service.

Use alarmmanager where you are registering your service as follows:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,ServiceStarter.class);
                    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1545, intent, 0);
                    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, alarmIntent);
```

then in ServiceStarter broadcastreceiver do following stuff...

```
public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (!ConstantData.isServiceRunning(YourService.class , context)){ //check service is running or not
            context.startService(new Intent(context , YourService.class));
        }
        else{
            Log.e("service-->>" , "service already running");
        }


        try {
        //set alarm for next 5 seconds...this will set alarm for every next 5 seconds

            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, ServiceStarter.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1545, intent2, 0);
            alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, alarmIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**ConstantData.isServiceRunning()** method:-

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Above code will fire alarmmanager every 5 seconds and check for if service is running or not. If service is running then it will do nothing and if service is stopped then it will start service again.

Comment: It helped me resolving the issue. Thanks alot !!

Comment: This won't solve the actual issue but instead try to brute force starting the service consuming a lot of battery juice in the process. Also it will stop working on Android 8 and higher.

Comment: yes, i know it but this is the only way which will work on every device. This will work in most of devices, even in Mi devices, also in vivo and oppo devices which contains their own optimization mechanism in their custom os. If you have any better solution that will work on all devices then please let me know. @Sander

Comment: This will not work on every device, calling `context.startService` from a `BroadcastReceiver` will result in an `IllegalStateException` on Android 8 and higher. The better solution depends a lot on what you're trying to achieve, it's simply not possible anymore to have your own service running in the background all the time.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I've tested it on Android 6.0 couple of days ago and that worked fine.  Tested on 7.0 today, but service stops here on 7.0 and 8.0.

Comment: Would you please help me to settle this for Android N (7.0) and O (8.0).

Comment: I think that should work perfectly because i am also using this code in my app and i also have tested on android 7.0 and it's works fine.  In your case, first of all you should make sure that the device you are testing contains autostart permission or not. If yes, then you should have to give autostart permission to work your service in background. and if No, then let me know how are you killing your app from recent?  Using clear all button or just removing only your app? It also gives different results so, test this case also and let me know what happens now. @AkhtarKhan

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Which autostart permission to work service in background?

Comment: All mobiles doesn't contains autostart permission. Some manufacturer(Mi, Vivo, Oppo,etc..) added this permission in their os for achieving bettery optimization. If you want to check that your device contains autostart permission or not then you can check it by going in settings. @AkhtarKhan

Comment: I've added Manfiest permission REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS. Secondly, setting alarm by setAndAllowWhileIdle. Its working on every phone now.

Comment: ok. Thanks for suggesting new solution to me. I will check it out. @AkhtarKhan

Comment: @JaydipKalkani Tested on phone with 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 and its working perfectly alright. But still not working on Android 8.0. Let me know if you can help it out.

Comment: @Sander on Android version > 8 to start Foreground Service from a BroadcastReceiver you MUST USE "startForegroundService" instead of "startService".
Anyway you SHOULDN'T USE ALARM-MANAGER, NEVER! It will consume a lot of battery, instead use JobService or JobIntentService by scheduling Periodic Job or re-scheduling latency jobs (periodic jobs doesn't works in Android version > 8)

Answer (score 0):

While an app is idle, there are limits to its use of background services. This does not apply to foreground services, which are more noticeable to the user.

reference: [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html)

Comment: Above docs explains about "Android 8.0 (API level 26) imposes limitations on what apps can do while running in the background". I'm getting issue on Android 6.0.